# Graph database - how to reference Nodes from within Relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm preparing a graph database (using neo4j) to handle the kind of social network scenario:

- Users can **Post** to their walls, sharing the Posts with either specific users
- Users can send **Messages** to others
- A **Message** can either be a text or "link" to the **Post**

So I came up with the following idea:

Users and Posts are the Nodes of the graph. When the user `A` creates a post `P` sharing it with both `B` and `C`, the following relationships are created: `A-[:posted]->p` and `p-[:shared_with]->B` and `p-[:shared_with]->C`. The `Post` data (id, text, date) are stored as properties of the `:posted` relation.

For messages it's similar: `A-[:messaged]->C` for example.

Now, if I want to share the post in a message, I include the `post_id` in `:messaged` properties. It allows me to pull all the messages (together with the posts linked) with a single Cypher query:

```
match (a:User) match (b) where a.username = "C" match a-[m:messaged]-b 
optional match (x:User)-[p:posted]->(post:Post)
where post.id = m.post_id
return distinct
m.post_id,
  startnode(m).username as from, 
  endnode(m).username as to ,
  x.username as PostAuthor,
  case x when null then "Message" else "Pulled Post" end as Type,
  case x when null then m.text else post.text end as Text, 
  m.date
order by m.date asc
```

It doesn't **look** right to me though - since on the graph there's no visual connection between the `Post` and the message. But, I can't set a relation between Node and Relation, right? How should I do it in order to have it designed properly?

Comment: I would model the sharing system with ACL groups and permissions in the graphs, rather than connecting each user to which a post is shared. Secondly for messaging system and links in the bodies, generally links to posts are represented as urls, not as internal ids

Comment: however you might want to connect the message with a "SPEAKS_ABOUT" relationship to a post. But this looks weird tbh.

Comment: But isn't id(post) exactly for that? to reference the node from somewhere else?

Comment: The message is a relationship in my model (maybe it should be a node? I'm not sure...). Can I connect relationship  to a relationship?

Comment: yes messages should be nodes. wanting to connect relationships to relationships is exactly telling you that you need an important part of your domain as nodes, hence messages nodes. No internal ids are proper to neo4j and deleted nodes ids are reused during the db lifecycle, so you MUST avoid it

Comment: The post data should live on the :Post not on the relationship

Comment: And as the (:Post) is a node you can connect it to a (:Message) node.

Comment: see the chapter on modelling communication in the free graph databases book (http://graphdatabases.com)

Answer (score 1):

In a model where post and message are both a node, your query would look like this:

```
match (a:User)<-[:FROM]-(m:Message)-[:TO]->(b:User) 
where a.username = "C" 
match (m)<-[:COMMENT]-(post:Post)<-[:POSTED]-(x:User)
return distinct
  m.id,a as from, b as to,
  x.username as PostAuthor,
  case x when null then "Message" else "Pulled Post" end as Type,
  case x when null then m.text else post.text end as Text, 
  m.date
order by m.date asc
```